# Is there a name for a counter that tracks time since an event last occurred?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word or short phrase to describe a counter that increments to show how much time has passed since an event occurred. A great example is a "days since last injury" counter.

[image: Simpsons "Days Without an Accident" counter]

Ideally this should be generic. My use case is a "time since last exception" in a program.

Comment: I'm not sure about a specific name for that kind of physical board in your photo. But could you make *tally* or *running tally* work in your context?

Comment: For your specific use case in programming, perhaps "uptime" would work.  "[noun] time during which a computer or machine is working"  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uptime

Comment: @James I suppose I'm looking for something that would work as the opposite of uptime. More of a "time since last program crash" but with a shorter phrase.

Comment: "Incident board" was the phrase that sprang to mind for me, but then I Googled it and not much came up except this TVTropes link: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XDaysSince I don't know how common this kind of marker is in real life, so I don't know if there's a standardized name for it.

Comment: Either an "elapsed time counter" or an "interval timer", for something that's quasi-technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be willing to call that an **[interval](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interval) timer**, but I am not aware of any standardized name for it.

Answer (score 2):

The most general term I can think of would be **stopwatch**; although this might not work in every context.

Answer (score 2):

[Intervalometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalometer)

Interval meter and interval timer are also valid terms.